# How do you use playwright locators to query dynamic css classes?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, playwright, css-modules

With Playwright, how can I get element's value based on CSS class path when using React with CSS Modules or with Styled Components?
The problem with both that they are generating a static hash, but they are different in different environments (development/staging) and probably will be different after each assets compilation.
How can I reliably access the same element on both environment?

Comment: you can also use xpath as selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use:

```
  data-test-id='your-id-name'
```

As described [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#define-explicit-contract-and-use-data-test-id).